# Can I turn off Office Auto Save feature using ARD?

Tags: mac-osx, scripting, remote-desktop, microsoft-office

I have around 300 OSX desktops, and I'm not looking forward to having to walk around to each one to turn off MS autosave, can this be done using Apple Remote Desktop and a script?

Answer (score 0):

Which Office and Mac OS X Version are you using?

Office for Mac 2011 only has an Auto Recovery save which stores a recovery version within `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 AutoRecovery`

The actual file is not overwritten unless you hit cmd + S or save in the menu.